why nr_involuntary_switches of a process runs on an isolated cpu is constantly increasing?
I have a server (linux 4.18+intel xeon) which has isolated cpus for latency-sensitive service.
I noticed that the service process's nr_involuntary_switches is gradually increasing every a few seconds by looking at the /proc/{pid}/sched.
My questions is: since the cpu is dedicated for the service process, how come there is still context-switches?

Periodically, (every 1/60th of a second in the olden days) the system scheduler interrupts your program to see if there's a "more runnable" task (actually, it just picks the "most runnable" task), disk I/O completes, the clock ticks, ... and nr_involuntary_switches gets incremented.
If you need deducated CPU access, investigate "real time", and "low latency kernels".

Isolating a CPU prevents tasks/processes from being assigned to or from the CPU by the scheduler. Why the system scheduler interrupted my program running on an isolated cpu?
